# Evitando duplicação de código sem o uso de switch/case na linguagem Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Amigos,

Tenho o seguinte código em Python:

```
data_hoje = time.strftime("%d %b %Y", time.gmtime() ) #data de hoje

data_desejada = time.strftime("%d %b %Y", time.gmtime(time.time() + (3600 * 24 * 2))) # daqui a 2 dias
```

Eu sei que em Python não temos a estrutura switch/case que é usada em outras linguagens. O Código acima está muito repetitivo. Como torná-lo mais "enxuto", ou seja, evitar o uso dos vários if/elif?

```
if data_hoje[0:2] == "01":
    data_nova = data_hoje[1:2] + data_hoje[2::] 

elif data_hoje[0:2] == "02":
    data_nova = data_hoje[1:2] + data_hoje[2::]

elif data_hoje[0:2] == "03":
    data_nova = data_hoje[1:2] + data_hoje[2::]

elif data_hoje[0:2] == "04":
    data_nova = data_hoje[1:2] + data_hoje[2::]

elif data_hoje[0:2] == "05":
    data_nova = data_hoje[1:2] + data_hoje[2::]

elif data_hoje[0:2] == "06":
    data_nova = data_hoje[1:2] + data_hoje[2::]

elif data_hoje[0:2] == "07":
    data_nova = data_hoje[1:2] + data_hoje[2::]

elif data_hoje[0:2] == "08":
    data_nova = data_hoje[1:2] + data_hoje[2::]

elif data_hoje[0:2] == "08":
    data_nova = data_hoje[1:2] + data_hoje[2::]

else:
    data_nova = data_hoje






if data_desejada[0:2] == "01":
    data_nova2 = data_desejada[1:2] + data_desejada[2::] 

elif data_desejada[0:2] == "02":
    data_nova2 = data_desejada[1:2] + data_desejada[2::]

elif data_desejada[0:2] == "03":
    data_nova2 = data_desejada[1:2] + data_desejada[2::]

elif data_desejada[0:2] == "04":
    data_nova2 = data_desejada[1:2] + data_desejada[2::]

elif data_desejada[0:2] == "05":
    data_nova2 = data_desejada[1:2] + data_desejada[2::]

elif data_desejada[0:2] == "06":
    data_nova2 = data_desejada[1:2] + data_desejada[2::]

elif data_desejada[0:2] == "07":
    data_nova2 = data_desejada[1:2] + data_desejada[2::]

elif data_desejada[0:2] == "08":
    data_nova2 = data_desejada[1:2] + data_desejada[2::]

elif data_desejada[0:2] == "08":
    data_nova2 = data_desejada[1:2] + data_desejada[2::]

else:
    data_nova2 = data_desejada
```

Comment: Nossa - esse código está absurdmente repetitivo -agora, não vejo como "switch casse" reduziria o número de linhas dele - as respostas refletem formas mais espertas de fazer isso sem  if/elif ou switch/case.

Agora - para fazer operações com datas, você deveria usar o módulo dattime do Python, e não fazer operções com texto, que podem quebrar de dezenas de formas diferentes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eu acho que estás a fazer coisas desnecessáriamente:

Podes reduzir isto:

```
data_hoje[1:2] + data_hoje[2::] # 1 Mar 2017
```

para:

```
data_hoje[1:] # 1 Mar 2017
```

Parece-me aqui que estás só a verificar se a data (dia) começa com um zero e a retirar esse 0 caso isso se verifique, então porque não tornar tudo mais simples e usar [ltrim](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_lstrip.htm):

```
data_hoje = time.strftime("%d %b %Y", time.gmtime()).lstrip('0') # 1 Mar 2017
data_desejada = time.strftime("%d %b %Y", time.gmtime(time.time() + (3600 * 24 * 2))).lstrip('0') # 3 Mar 2017
```

Por ultimo, podes simplesmente usar `%e` na tua função `strftime`:

```
data_hoje = time.strftime("%e %b %Y", time.gmtime()).strip() # 1 Mar 2017
data_desejada = time.strftime("%e %b %Y", time.gmtime(time.time() + (3600 * 24 * 2))).strip() # 3 Mar 2017
```

Aqui uso o `strip()` só para tirar o espaço que vai haver em vez do `0`.

E um reparo nas tuas condições, poderiam apenas ser:

```
if data_hoje.startswith('0'): # caso a data comece com um 0
    data_nova = data_hoje[1:]
```

Este ultimo é só um exmplo do que podias fazer em vez dessas condições todas e o quanto podias reduzir o código, as duas soluções que dei em cima são melhores.

Comment: obrigado! Existe algo semelhante ao switch/case em Python?

Comment: @EdS nop, com if/elif podes alcançar o mesmo. De qualquer maneira não precisas para este caso, lê bem a minha explicação. Todo o teu código fica reduzido a essas linhas que coloquei, um dos dois primeiros exemplos que coloquei

Answer (score 4):

Usa Loop:

```
for i in range(1,9,1):
  if data_hoje[0:2] == "0"+str(i):
    data_nova = data_hoje[1:2] + data_hoje[2::]
else:
  data_nova = data_hoje

for i in range(1,9,1):
  if data_hoje[0:2] == "0"+str(i):
    data_nova2 = data_hoje[1:2] + data_hoje[2::]
else:
  data_nova2 = data_hoje
```

Comment: ,Obrigado! data_hoje = time.strftime("%d %b %Y", time.gmtime() ) imprime, por exemplo, 01 Mar 2017. A ideia era transformar isso em 1 Mar 2017. Alguma maneira melhor?

Comment: import datetime /

  /  data = datetime.date.today()

  /  print(data.day) / a barra é só pra separar, usa a classe datetime

Answer (score 2):

Se quer simplesmente um código menor você também pode tentar um loop simplificado em uma função:

```
def atribuiData(data):
    data_nova = [(data[1:2] + data[2::]) for i in range(1,9) if data[0:2] == ("0{0}".format(i))]
    if not data_nova:
        data_nova = data
    return data_nova

data_nova = atribuiData(data_hoje)
data_nova2 = atribuiData(data_desejada)
```